# How insert new record to an existing collection : Sails.js

Tags: javascript, model, sails.js

I am very new to sailsjs . For data storage **Sails model** plays vital role.

I have gone through the documentation and am able to create collection.

But don't find any way to **insert record to an existing collection** .

Please give me example of the same.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What did you try/what's your use case?

Comment: Reference for `.create()` is at https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelMethods.md#create-values-callback-

Comment: @sgress454 Link broken.

Answer (score 0):

by using collection.create() method
for e.g

```
User.create({"firstName": "Jhon", "lastName": "Doe"});
```

where User is your collection model name